# Merging year and week column to create datetime and sorting in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, calendar

Sample Data

```
Year  Week_No  Value
2015   52       3
2016   2        7
2015   51       5
2016   1        6
2015   50       4
```

Below is the code that I have tried

```
import datetime
d = "2015-50"
r = datetime.datetime.strptime(d + '-1', "%Y-%W-%w")
print(r)
2015-12-14 00:00:00
```

How to move ahead to create a datetime column?

Comment: Use `pd.to_datetime` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in pandas is best use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with add last value `-1` for day of week:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Year.astype(str) + '-' + 
                                df.Week_No.astype(str) + '-1', format="%Y-%W-%w")

print (df)
   Year  Week_No  Value   datetime
0  2015       52      3 2015-12-28
1  2016        2      7 2016-01-11
2  2015       51      5 2015-12-21
3  2016        1      6 2016-01-04
4  2015       50      4 2015-12-14
```

Comment: what if I want Friday to be the weekday instead of Monday ?

Comment: @AB14 - I think `-1` should be changed to `-5`

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
df['datetime'] = df.apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(str(x.Year) + '-' + str(x.Week_No) + '-1', "%Y-%W-%w"), axis=1)
```

output:

```
   Year  Week_No  Value   datetime
0  2015       52      3 2015-12-28
1  2016        2      7 2016-01-11
2  2015       51      5 2015-12-21
3  2016        1      6 2016-01-04
4  2015       50      4 2015-12-14
```

Comment: What is your pandas version?

Comment: 0.25.3.  how about yours?

Comment: My is `0.25.1`, I was surprise because your solution raise error for me.

Comment: I updated mine to wrap with strings. i don't want any errors raised. on different versions. BTW i hope you enjoyed my enthusiasm for all of your questions the other day. They are very good

Comment: yop, I try upgrade pandas, because 2 times problem I dont have last version... Do you use anaconda?

Comment: i use pip3 for my installs, haven't tried anaconda yet